# Watered down axiom of choice

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

I'm wondering what the following statement is equivalent to in an intuitionistic framework.

> For a union of sets $C = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} X_i,$ if $S \in C,$ there
>   exists $s \in I$ such that $S \in X_s.$

In classical logic, the proof just relies on ZF and the law of the excluded middle. Indeed, if there does not exist $s$ such that $S \in X_s,$ then $S \not\in X_s$ for all $s \in I,$ hence $S \not\in C$ by the definition of union, contradiction.

Comment: The very same strengthening of the meaning of the existential quantifier that pervades intuitionistic logic comes into play in the definition of union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell, it's not so much an important axiom or theorem as the definition of $\bigcup$ (or rather it would be, if you changed the *if* to *iff*). As it stands, it follows from the *iff* version of the definition.